# Delphi function comparing content of two TStream?

Tags: delphi, stream, compare, delphi-xe

I need to compare if two **TStream** descendant **have the same content**.
The only interesting result for me is the boolean Yes / No.

I'm going to code a **simple loop** checking byte after byte the streams content's.

But I'm **curious** to know if there is an already existing function. I haven't found any inside DelphiXE or JCL/JVCL libs.

Of course, the two streams have the same size !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exactly, as Nickolay O. said you should read your stream in blocks and use CompareMem. Here is an example (including size test) ...

```
function IsIdenticalStreams(Source, Destination: TStream): boolean;
const Block_Size = 4096;

var Buffer_1: array[0..Block_Size-1] of byte;
    Buffer_2: array[0..Block_Size-1] of byte;
    Buffer_Length: integer;

begin
  Result := False;

  if Source.Size <> Destination.Size then
    Exit;

  while Source.Position < Source.Size do
    begin
      Buffer_Length := Source.Read(Buffer_1, Block_Size);
      Destination.Read(Buffer_2, Block_Size);

      if not CompareMem(@Buffer_1, @Buffer_2, Buffer_Length) then
        Exit;
    end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: Perhaps it helps when you set both stream positions to 0 before starting your loop.

Comment: Or load the whole streams into 2 memorystreams and feed those to comparemem.

Comment: @Uwe Raabe - +1, you're totally right, @Remko - +1, you're probably right too, I hope that CompareMem exits immediately when it finds the byte difference

Comment: I don't like TMemoryStream because it's a disaster for large files due to its need to have a contiguous block of memory. Perhaps that will be fine in dcc64 but until then it's worth avoiding. This code won't work as it stands for streams whose size is less than Block_Size because you will be comparing random stack noise.

Comment: @daemon_x CompareMem does indeed short circuit. But so what, with a 4K block you wouldn't notice the difference.

Comment: @daemon_x the simple fix for this is to note the return value from the call to TStream.Read as BytesRead and pass Min(BytesRead, Block_Size) to CompareMem.

Comment: @David Heffernan - yes, you were faster :)

Comment: @David Heffernan: TMemoryStream works fine as long as you preallocate memory calling SetSize if you know what size it will be in advance. Anyway to compare two streams I wouldn't load them fully into memory, better to start loading, compare and stop at the first mismatch, especially for large streams on disk (or other "slow" sources, i.e. a database field).

Comment: @David Heffernan - I wrote this piece of code on the fly, so if you have some time, modify it and post to your answer :)

Comment: @daemon_x That's better! And I don't know what I was going on about with `Min(Buffer_Length, Block_Size)` since that is always equal to Buffer_Length. D'oh!

Comment: @Idsandon No it does not work fine! You can either have a stream > 2GB in which it certainly fails. Or alternatively there may not be a large enough block of available contiguous address space. This happens well before you get to 2GB under most normal usage patterns.

Answer (score 9):

The **IsIdenticalStreams** function posted by daemon_x is excellent - but needs one adjustment to work properly.  (Uwe Raabe caught the issue already.)  It is *critical that you reset the stream positions before starting the loop* - or this procedure will probably return an incorrect TRUE if the two streams were already accessed outside this function.

This is the final solution that works every time.  I just renamed the function to suit my naming conventions.  Thank you daemon_x for the elegant solution.

```
function StreamsAreIdentical(Stream1, Stream2: TStream): boolean;
const
  Block_Size = 4096;

var
  Buffer_1: array[0..Block_Size-1] of byte;
  Buffer_2: array[0..Block_Size-1] of byte;
  Buffer_Length: integer;

begin

  Result := False;

  if Stream1.Size <> Stream2.Size then exit;

  // These two added lines are critical for proper operation 
  Stream1.Position := 0;
  Stream2.Position := 0;

  while Stream1.Position < Stream1.Size do
  begin

    Buffer_Length := Stream1.Read(Buffer_1, Block_Size);
    Stream2.Read(Buffer_2, Block_Size);
    if not CompareMem(@Buffer_1, @Buffer_2, Buffer_Length) then exit;

  end;

  Result := True;

end;
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no such built-in function. Only one thing I can recommend - read not byte-to-byte, but using blocks of 16-64kbytes, that would be much faster.

Comment: yeah, large blocks with calls to CompareMem will get this done

Comment: ok, thx for this first answer and the tips about large blocks. I will accept answer from daemon_x as there is the full code with the CompareMem() usage.

Answer (score 4):

Answers from **user532231** and **Mike** are working in 99% cases, but there are **additional checks to be made**!

Descendants of TStream can be almost anything, so **it's not guaranteed that Stream.Read will return same amount of data**, even if streams are of the same length (stream descendant can also download data, so may return readed=0 bytes, while waiting for next chunk). Streams can be also on completelly different media and stream read error could occur on just one.

For 100% working code all these checks should be made. I modified the function from Mike.

*If this function is used for example to rewrite stream 2 if not identical to Stream1, all errors should be checked. When function result is True, everthing is ok, but if it is False, it would be very smart to check if Streams are actually different or just some error occured.*

**Edited: *Added some additional checks, FilesAreIdentical function based on StreamsAreIdentical and usage example.***

```
// Usage example

var lError: Integer;
...
 if FilesAreIdentical(lError, 'file1.ext', 'file2.ext')
    then Memo1.Lines.Append('Files are identical.')
    else case lError of
           0: Memo1.Lines.Append('Files are NOT identical!');
           1: Memo1.Lines.Append('Files opened, stream read exception raised!');
           2: Memo1.Lines.Append('File does not exist!');
           3: Memo1.Lines.Append('File open exception raised!');
         end; // case
...

// StreamAreIdentical

function StreamsAreIdentical(var aError: Integer;
                             const aStream1, aStream2: TStream;
                             const aBlockSize: Integer = 4096): Boolean;

var
  lBuffer1: array of byte;
  lBuffer2: array of byte;
  lBuffer1Readed,
  lBuffer2Readed,
  lBlockSize: integer;

begin
  Result:=False;
  aError:=0;
  try
    if aStream1.Size <> aStream2.Size
       then Exit;

    aStream1.Position:=0;
    aStream2.Position:=0;

    if aBlockSize>0
       then lBlockSize:=aBlockSize
       else lBlockSize:=4096;

    SetLength(lBuffer1, lBlockSize);
    SetLength(lBuffer2, lBlockSize);

    lBuffer1Readed:=1; // just for entering while

    while (lBuffer1Readed > 0) and (aStream1.Position < aStream1.Size) do
    begin
      lBuffer1Readed := aStream1.Read(lBuffer1[0], lBlockSize);
      lBuffer2Readed := aStream2.Read(lBuffer2[0], lBlockSize);

      if (lBuffer1Readed <> lBuffer2Readed) or ((lBuffer1Readed <> lBlockSize) and (aStream1.Position < aStream1.Size))
         then Exit;

      if not CompareMem(@lBuffer1[0], @lBuffer2[0], lBuffer1Readed)
         then Exit;
    end; // while

    Result:=True;
  except
    aError:=1; // stream read exception
  end;
end;


// FilesAreIdentical using function StreamsAreIdentical

function FilesAreIdentical(var aError: Integer;
                           const aFileName1, aFileName2: String;
                           const aBlockSize: Integer = 4096): Boolean;

var lFileStream1,
    lFilestream2: TFileStream;

begin
 Result:=False;
 try
   if not (FileExists(aFileName1) and FileExists(aFileName2))
      then begin
        aError:=2; // file not found
        Exit;
      end;

   lFileStream1:=nil;
   lFileStream2:=nil;
   try
     lFileStream1:=TfileStream.Create(aFileName1, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
     lFileStream2:=TFileStream.Create(aFileName2, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
     result:=StreamsAreIdentical(aError, lFileStream1, lFileStream2, aBlockSize);
   finally
     if lFileStream2<>nil
        then lFileStream2.Free;

     if lFileStream1<>nil
        then lFileStream1.Free;
   end; // finally
 except
   aError:=3; // file open exception
 end; // except
end;
```

Comment: +1 for the interesting remark. Thx for answering a quite old question, I'm still amazed to see how [software] people are so devoted to share and continuously improve and exchange ... I've never seen this elsewhere :)

Comment: TridenT: Just making the world a better place ;)

Comment: I would definitely let the exception to be thrown. If something goes wrong during reading and you'll "eat that problem" and return just a boolean, no one will ever be able to determine what was the problem. And, there is no need to compare `aBlockSize` of memory, but just `Buffer1Readed` or `Buffer2Readed` (they will equal).

Comment: TLama: The only exception possible here is "Stream Read Exception", so it's safe just to return aError:=True on False result. I personally prefer not to dusturb the program execution, but that is matter of taste and opinion :P Also I prefer not to statically encode buffer size (changed const to function const parameter) and I moved buffers from stack to heap. Once again, this is a matter of programmers taste and how much flexibility he wants. About CompareMem you are absolutely right, I changed to Buffer1Readed since both are the same!

Comment: You're right that it's matter of taste... Anyway, use `@` char followed by the name of the user (it will trigger the autosuggestion while you'll start typing) to address someone to be notified about a new comment (like e.g. `@TLama` would notify me). I didn't used that since you are the owner of the post and so you're always being notified as well as the question owner. Thanks and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @david would this work on a stream that is less than 4096 in size? `(Buffer1Readed <> aBlockSize)` what happens?

Comment: @MerlinW. Yes it would, it would even work on a stream of size 0. ;) It compares only how much was acutally readed, and if it's not same size, it exits before that `if (Buffer1Readed <> Buffer2Readed)`, and this part `or ((Buffer1Readed <> aBlockSize) and (aStream1.Position < aStream1.Size))` allows to be readed less than aBlock size **only** when at the end of stream. This is actually what you asked ;)

Comment: @MerlinW. Actually while working today on other project i found out that CompareMem is not as safe as Length or Move, which normally operates on zero length dynamic array (nil). Function would crash if someone, for some strange reason, would chose a block size of 0 length (and could even result in endless loop, because 0 bytes would be read while expecting to reach end of stream). So i added more checks, and usage example with FilesAreIdentical function, using StreamsAreIdentical ;)

Comment: @TridenT - I think the age of the question is irrelevant. we re here to teach/learn :)