# What is the fastest solution to compare JPEG image? (ignoring metadata, just the "pixels")

Tags: delphi, comparison, jpeg

When I search the words "JPEG" and "metadata", I have many answers to manipulate the metadata... and this is the opposite I want... ;o)

I have written a function which exactly works like I want... (if images are similar, and only the metadata change or not, the function returns `True` ; if at least one pixel changes, it returns `False`) but, I'd like to improve the performance...

The bottleneck is the `bmp.Assign(jpg);`

```
function CompareImages(fnFrom, fnTo: TFileName): Boolean;
var
  j1, j2: TJpegImage;
  b1, b2: TBitmap;
  s1, s2: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Result := False;
sw1.Start;
  j1 := TJpegImage.Create;
  j2 := TJpegImage.Create;
sw1.Stop;
sw2.Start;
  s1 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  s2 := TMemoryStream.Create;
sw2.Stop;
//sw3.Start;
  b1 := TBitmap.Create;
  b2 := TBitmap.Create;
//sw3.Stop;
  try
  sw1.Start;
    j1.LoadFromFile(fnFrom);
    j2.LoadFromFile(fnTo);
  sw1.Stop;

            // the very long part...
            sw3.Start;
              b1.Assign(j1);
              b2.Assign(j2);
            sw3.Stop;


  sw4.Start;
    b1.SaveToStream(s1);
    b2.SaveToStream(s2);
  sw4.Stop;
  sw2.Start;
    s1.Position := 0;
    s2.Position := 0;
  sw2.Stop;
  sw5.Start;
    Result := IsIdenticalStreams(s1, s2);
  sw5.Stop;
  finally
//  sw3.Start;
    b1.Free;
    b2.Free;
//  sw3.Stop;
  sw2.Start;
    s1.Free;
    s2.Free;
  sw2.Stop;
  sw1.Start;
    j1.Free;
    j2.Free;
  sw1.Stop;
  end;
end;
```

sw1, ..., sw5 are [TStopWatch](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch), I used to identify the time spent.

IsIdenticalStreams comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4606388/596852).

If I directly compare the `TJpegImage`, the streams are different...

Any better way to code that?

Regards,

W.

**Update:**

Testing some solutions extract from the comments, I have the same performance with this code:

```
type
  TMyJpeg = class(TJPEGImage)
    public
      function Equals(Graphic: TGraphic): Boolean; override;
  end;

...

function CompareImages(fnFrom, fnTo: TFileName): Boolean;
var
  j1, j2: TMyJpeg;
begin
  sw1.Start;
  Result := False;
  j1 := TMyJpeg.Create;
  j2 := TMyJpeg.Create;
  try
    j1.LoadFromFile(fnFrom);
    j2.LoadFromFile(fnTo);
  Result := j1.Bitmap.Equals(j2.Bitmap);
  finally
    j1.Free;
    j2.Free;
  end;
  sw1.Stop;
end;
```

Any way to directly access the pixel data bytes from the file (skipping the metadata bytes) without bitmap conversion?

Comment: I would extract the pixel data without meta-data and use md5-hashing to compare the contents. Might be a useful idea to try out...

Comment: @ChristopheD: Any idea how to directly extract the pixel data?

Comment: why do you need to compare the pixels? Isn't the bitstream enough?

Comment: @Whiler: in Delphi not immediately, sorry, but I'm sure the Delphi experts will come in with a great answer ;-)

Comment: @James: I'm not sure I exactly understand what is the bitstream... does it contains the metadata or not? if yes... I don't.. if it's only the *visual* data... how to access it?

Comment: One brute force way would be to look at the bitmap for both images and loop using scanline. It would probably stop very shortly if images are not the same...

Comment: I think you should work out a solution depending on image size, system performance, expected time/compare, etc. if your images are not huge(10MP+), I **assume** a scanline like @François suggested would do the job just great, you may want to scan first line test, scan last line test, scan second line test, etc. it could improve performance...

Comment: @Dorin, the best is to compare the block behind a header without any compromise like MBo tried to explain (I'm not sure if that's as easy as it's stated there for all cases, but [`here`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Image-MetaData-JPEG/lib/Image/MetaData/JPEG/Structures.pod) e.g. is a good looking unofficial explanation). Then might be the `TGraphic.Equals` of the `TJPEGImage.Bitmap` in case OP wants to compare the images visually, what decompresses the JPEGs to bitmaps and compare their pixels with `CompareMem`. That's for case when they would be e.g. compressed with a different way, but...

Comment: @Dorin, ...visually would be definitely the same. The problem for this is the `TJPEGImage.Bitmap` getter which does the decompression, except several steps there is also the `jpeg_read_scanlines` inside, so you might try to create your own function, where you would decompress the two images collaterally and once you would find a difference you're done and have a result. I wanted to point out that scanline of the bitmaps here would decompress both images and use an iteration, but `TBitmap.Equals` use for bitmap data comparision the `CompareMem` and do the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JPEG file consists of chunks, which types are identified by markers. The structure of chunks (except for stand-alone SOI, EOI, RSTn):

```
chunk type marker (big-endian FFxx)
chunk length (big-endian word)
data (length-2 bytes)
```

**Edit:** SOS chunk is limited by another marker, not by length.

Metadata chunks start with APPn marker (FFEn), except for APP0 (FFE0) marker with JFIF title.

So we can read and compare only significant chunks and ignore APPn chunks and COM chunk (as TLama noticed).

Example: hex view of some jpeg file:
[image]

It starts with SOI (Start Of Image) marker FFD8 (stand-alone, without length),

then APP0 chunk (FFE0) with length = 16 bytes,

then APP1 chunk (FFE1), which contains metadata (EXIF data, NIKON COOLPIX name etc), so we can ignore 9053 bytes (23 5D) and check next chunk marker at address 2373, and so on...

**Edit:** Simple parsing example:

```
var
  jp: TMemoryStream;
  Marker, Len: Word;
  Position: Integer;
  PBA: PByteArray;

  procedure ReadLenAndMovePosition;
  begin
    Inc(Position, 2);
    Len := Swap(PWord(@PBA[Position])^);
    Inc(Position, Len);
  end;

begin
  jp := TMemoryStream.Create;
  jp.LoadFromFile('D:\3.jpg');
  Position := 0;
  PBA := jp.Memory;

  while (Position < jp.Size - 1) do begin
    Marker := Swap(PWord(@PBA[Position])^);
    case Marker of
      $FFD8: begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add('Start Of Image');
          Inc(Position, 2);
        end;
      $FFD9: begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add('End Of Image');
          Inc(Position, 2);
        end;
      $FFE0: begin
          ReadLenAndMovePosition;
          Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('JFIF Header Len: %d', [Len]));
        end;
      $FFE1..$FFEF, $FFFE: begin
          ReadLenAndMovePosition;
          Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('APPn or COM Len: %d Ignored', [Len]));
        end;
      $FFDA: begin
          //SOS marker, data stream, ended by another marker except for RSTn
          Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('SOS data stream started at %d', [Position]));
          Inc(Position, 2);
          while Position < jp.Size - 1 do begin
            if PBA[Position] = $FF then
              if not (PBA[Position + 1] in [0, $D0..$D7]) then begin
                Inc(Position, 2);
                Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('SOS data stream ended at %d',
                  [Position]));
                Break;
              end;
            Inc(Position);
          end;
        end;
    else begin
        ReadLenAndMovePosition;
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Marker %x Len: %d Significant', [Marker, Len]));
      end;
    end;
  end;
  jp.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the structure explanation... I try to implement the code and come back later to give feedback...

Comment: To be honest... I'm lost... the "**SOS data stream started**" is exactly what I need... so, this should be ok... but, what is the **Significant** markers? Why are they Significant? as all my pic is the same behind (same regarding the bytes)

Comment: It is my tag - I added "Ignored" to output for metadata and comment chunks, and "significant" for chunks concerning real data - both SOS stream and Huffman and quantization tables